# XMLHttpRequest is not working on chrome on mobile device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on core javascript on front end and php in back end and for sending and receiving data from back end, I am using XMLHttpRequest. My code for post request is:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', BASE_URL+'index.php/dashboard/saveEndPoint');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

var messageObj = {
  endPoint: endPoint,
  ipAddress:userip,
  url:window.location.href,
  browser:"Chrome"
}
request.send(JSON.stringify(messageObj));
```

This code working fine in chrome and firefox on desktop devices. But when I am using chrome on mobile devices with android operating system, It's not working. Not sending request.
I debug code by connecting mobile device with desktop chrome(crome://inspect) but it is showing no request.

Help me to find its solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Who make this request? button or some click event?

Comment: This code is running on load of document.

Comment: Can you show us this code? Maybe the problem is there

Comment: Have you set Content Security Policy meta tag in your `<head>` tag of the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem for not working of my code. It is due if-else condition in which, I put this code and because of not able to identify chrome on mobile with my if condition, It is not running ajax code.
So thank you the scion and everyone to help me find solution.